# How to get the phonenumber using google places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm writing a code to get the near by locations as prompted by the user using Node.js and making a call to Google's places API. and the call is as below.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=garage+near+corner+of+
fifth+avenue+NY&key=myApiKey
```

basically here I'm searching for the Garage near the 5th avenue New York. and the response that I get is as below.

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "next_page_token": "CqQCHgEAAKUUxRRzEF_vLKTGE5CLg-kBW7K8ot040l4zcsNHEByHpvjrhZZVOWcyCiPBbtErrX9QZNQ9dZQXCaxynnaJonFjF23_PPhWAmIfIRbY40E4gFioA5o4Gm3_OjkOicROypQQlArqaf2ub6vGoMwDKU1eP8m6SFmiMwm1cS_mghR0IWJ2Q9mH5jqpPtWJd2ENX3VCrDPeoOfhaxHAg3DIG7-eh7WYMlT9r6KAERCok-fXnjI49QVrezZYK52aCY3qeLSPLeXonrE2a79jfEdV1EhpBvb4fV2SB2oysCc_xK_Kv3FW6-Ir3WK2jXslrfRvFk7sIRxtgqAlZ2xCZ43oi7DeTl5733S5j4pbFZQHgsg9grLApa_H_wTN2xN1K9UsEhIQOf7B6Gnh668FPRTZe4X78BoUOMt8UiiVZR-YDJDb5AwyME7yYuY",
    "results": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "39 W 23rd St, New York, NY 10010, United States",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40.742537,
                    "lng": -73.99092399999999
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.7437215802915,
                        "lng": -73.9896989197085
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.7410236197085,
                        "lng": -73.99239688029151
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
            "id": "b075e432a0597a31ceaf3062747999291d8d8cf7",
            "name": "Park-it 23-24 Operating Corp",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": false,
                "weekday_text": []
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJJalOaKRZwokRNLnbupB5UrY",
            "reference": "CmRSAAAA-HGHWnLtBTIkRA7MlY1sjb8jDIxJQokfHSfQ_MWcLLM7lNB_MlUOwO0TcrQO8IYbUz1_l-HiehIwZ3hvg3sHEAiV-ZYpNL11gY15gz6hQsUFFKEkkfqoo_9R1PzVBd9CEhD7AxenKMzgH0LK4lNPFC8GGhSKMjd_5UnZyA3VRJrRYaw79QcxVg",
            "types": [
                "parking",
                "point_of_interest",
                "establishment"
            ]
        }
.
.
.
.
}
```

I the result received there is no `phoneNumber` available. can you please let me know if I'm using the correct API to get the near by places and how can I get the phone number along with the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there is no way to get phone number from the Places API search response. In order to get a phone number you have to execute a Places details request for each individual place ID.

E.g. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJJalOaKRZwokRNLnbupB5UrY&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The response will contain fields `formatted_phone_number` and `international_phone_number`

```
...
 "adr_address":"39 W 23rd St, New York, NY 10010-4295, USA",
"formatted_address":"39 W 23rd St, New York, NY 10010, USA",
"formatted_phone_number":"(212) 727-0141",
"geometry":{
  "location":{
    "lat":40.742537,"lng":-73.99092399999999
  },
  "viewport":{
    "northeast":{
      "lat":40.7437215802915,"lng":-73.9896989197085
    },
    "southwest":{
      "lat":40.7410236197085,"lng":-73.99239688029151
    }
  }
},
"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
"id":"b075e432a0597a31ceaf3062747999291d8d8cf7",
"international_phone_number":"+1 212-727-0141",
"name":"Park-it 23-24 Operating Corp",
...
```

I can also see that somebody tried to file a feature request for this in Google issue tracker back in 2011, however Google closed this feature request as infeasible

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820573

Feel free to create a new feature request in [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309), hopefully Google may reconsider it in 2017.

Comment: Seems it's closed. Any news about it?